# sql cach memory

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 10 records and an ID field as primary key.
Also many of my queries in do not include `ORDER BY id`. As an example, they look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `branch`
```

My problem started when I deleted the record with ID `1` by mistake, and then to correct my mistake, I inserted a record with the same ID and contents.
But now, in all my queries the later inserted row is the last one.
I mean, the order of IDs is: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1.

What I want is, to have the records returned ordered by ID, like it was before the delete but I cant add `ORDER BY id` in all the queries, since there are a so many queries like this in many files.

Please help me,
Thank you, Omry.

Comment: Perhaps adding a primary index on `id` might work. But the best bet is to modify the code and assume nothing in the ordering in results

Comment: `ID` is auto increment?

Comment: Why do you not do update on `ID`?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To overcome your problem, you can `SET foreign_key_checks=0` then drop your table and recreate it, insert the values from ID 1 to 10 in order, and then again `SET foreign_key_checks=1`. This will most probably solve your problem.

**But my advice is** always to use `ORDER BY`.

Since you cannot trust the order of the records that are returned from MySQL as a result of `SELECT`. MySQL, by default, returns the result in the order that it has stored the them, and it stores the record anywhere it finds a "hole".

That means if you make a batch insert it "might" take up the sequential memory allocation. Now if you delete a record from this set, you make a hole, that is occupied by subsequent inserts, and it reflects the same in `SELECT`.

Comment: OK thank you, I am using ORDER BY, this is simple :)

Comment: To be more emphatic: if you require the output to be in a certain order, but you don't specify `ORDER BY`, then your code is _broken_, or working by luck. SQL does not guarantee the order of the output unless there is an `ORDER BY` clause.